# How to preview the layout for ~ 21 inch device in android eclipse sdk?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I am working on a project specialize for the >19 inch android device
so , in the eclipse sdk I found the most largest size is the 10" 1920*1080 of the nexus 10.

Are there any way to preview the 21" device on eclipse? since I somehow use dp for the width, height , margin, so I need to make sure everything is correct in it.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Thanks for upvoting.. Also, the coming device is in higher resolution eg. 4k the eclipse run much slow and always out of memory, how to tackle it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new device definition in AVD, setting the device type to *Android TV*

For this make sure you have installed from SDK Manager the **Android TV System Image**

[image]

Or [Google TV Add-On](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_addon?csw=1) if you use previous SDK version.

If you pay attention to [TV Design Recommendations](http://developer.android.com/preview/tv/design/index.html) you should have no design problems.